# SQL Server 2012 Express Full Text Search User Instance

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search, user-instance

Is it possible to install Full Text Search feature in user instance in Server Server 2012? We use user instances locally and now I want to use this search feature. But I don't see it in the drop down of available instances to add the feature to when running Sql Server installer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full-text is not supported on User Instances. You have to use the default MSSQLSERVER instance or install a new regular instance.